# Update Dropdown Value

Tags: php

I have a country dropdown

```
<select name="country"  class="form-control"/>
    <option>Select a Country</option>
    <?php foreach($country_list as $country) :?>

      <option value="<?php echo $account_result->Country;?>"
      <?php
      if($country->id==$account_result->Country)
        {echo 'selected="selected"';};?>>
      <?php echo $country->name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

but while updating I am getting only selected value id it's not changing.

Answer (score 0):

You setting same value to all options change this line:
`<option value="<?php echo $account_result->Country;?>"`
to:
`<option value="<?php echo $country->id;?>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

You have added wrong value in option

```
<select name="country"  class="form-control"/>
    <option>Select a Country</option>
        <?php foreach($country_list as $country) :?>

          <option value="<?php echo $country->id;?>"
          <?php
          if($country->id==$account_result->Country)
            {echo 'selected="selected"';};?>>
          <?php echo $country->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $country->id == $account_result->Country ?"selected":"";?>
```

your `$country->id` and `$account_result->Country` should be same value example

ex: 44=44

then it will be get selected in default page load.

and you have to set the option value as like this.

```
<option value="<?php echo $country->id;?>"
```